# Isotope.js - AJAX and container height

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, jquery-isotope

I am working on a website that uses Isotope.js to sort a portfolio.  There is also a button that users can click to AJAX load more posts.

Here is a link to the temporary website:  https://contactlenzes.com.

This is how I initiated Isotope.js:

```
    // Portfolio isotope filter
$(window).load(function() {
    var $container = $('.projects');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '*',
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        }
    });
    $('.taxonomies a').click(function() {
        $('.taxonomies .active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector,
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

And this is my AJAX file:

```
jQuery(function($){


var $content = $('.projects');
var $loader = $('#more_posts');
var ppp = 4;
var offset = $('.projects').find('.project').length;

$loader.on( 'click', load_ajax_posts );

function load_ajax_posts() {
    if ( !($loader.hasClass('post_loading_loader') || $loader.hasClass('post_no_more_posts')) ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: screenReaderText.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                'ppp': ppp,
                'offset': offset,
                'action': 'mytheme_more_post_ajax'
            },
            beforeSend : function () {
                $loader.addClass('post_loading_loader').html( screenReaderText.loading );
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var $data = $(data);
                if ($data.length) {
                    var $newElements = $data.css({ opacity: 0 });



                    $content.append($newElements);

                    $content.isotope( 'appended', $newElements );

                    $content.isotope( 'reloadItems' );  // https://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#reloaditems

                    $content.isotope('layout'); // https://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#layout


                    $newElements.animate({ opacity: 1 });

                    $loader.removeClass('post_loading_loader').html(screenReaderText.loadmore);

                } else {

                    $loader.removeClass('post_loading_loader').addClass('post_no_more_posts').html(screenReaderText.noposts);

                }
            },
            error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $loader.html($.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText) + ' :: ' + textStatus + ' :: ' + errorThrown);
                console.log(jqXHR);
            },
        });
    }

    offset += ppp;
    return false;

}


});
```

Here is the problem!

The script the loads the posts.  But when the posts are loaded Isotope.js does not recalculated the height of the container.

As you can observe here:

[image: Isotope.js screenshot]

And here:

[image: Inspector]

Pressing the filter button, fixes the issue.

So how can I force Isotope.js to recalculated the height of the container when new posts are added via AJAX?

Or replicate the effect pressing the filter has... ?

I hope I am making sense.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone stumbles upon this issue.

I needed to wrap the `$content.isotope('layout');`  once images have loaded, as such:

```
$newElements.imagesLoaded(function(){
$content.isotope('layout');
});
```

More info can be found here:
https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/